# Add async checking before uploading image to s3 via Froala editor

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, file-upload, froala

I'm using the froala editor within my angular application and for that I'm using

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-froala-wysiwyg

I'm uploading images to s3 via froala, and it works.

Now I've a requirement that, before uploading the image I need to make a api call to my server and based on the response I need to decide whether to upload the image or not.

Here I saw an event `'image.beforeUpload'` and if we return false from this event then the current action will be cancel and image will not be uploaded.

But in my case I'm making a api call from the event and as it's asynchronous it's not returning any `false` instantly. So the image is being uploaded instantly. I tried to return promise, but that didn't help.

Can someone tell me ehat will be the best solution in this case?